# Leaflet: Move map on initial view

Tags: javascript, image, view, leaflet, translate3d

Is it poosible to move the image on the x axe? If I midify the translate3d(-20px,...,...) it works for me.

But if I zoom or drag the map it will be reseted.

For exmaple I have an absolute container and want to show parallel this 2 elements.

```
My example: http://jsfiddle.net/user9090900/fs8h21ap/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `panBy()` method of `L.Map`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-panby), e.g. `map.panBy([20, 0])`.

Comment: It works, but not in combination with `map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds([0,0], [height,width]));`

Comment: You have a trivial race condition. You set the map center to `0, 0`, then `setMaxBounds()` starts a panning animation that **takes time to finish**, and you are probably running `panBy()` before the animation ends. See https://jsfiddle.net/fs8h21ap/10/

Comment: Yes I see the problem. First the panBy animates, then setMaxBounds center the image. [https://jsfiddle.net/user9090900/fs8h21ap/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/user9090900/fs8h21ap/12/)
Is there any alternative available for MaxBounds?
Or is it possible to use `setMaxBounds` callback or on ready function?